# Angular Dynamic Mat Tab - How to add newly created tab as the first tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating a Dynamic Tab using Mat-tab. The new tab is created and it is working fine. But my requirement is to show the newly created as the first tab. How to insert the newly created tab to first. Anyone please help. Thanks in advance...

Here is the stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/angular/epealnoxvlg?file=app%2Ftab-group-dynamic-example.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a problem if you are in tab 0 and add a new tab -the "selected tab not change", so to take account of this you can write

```
addTab(selectAfterAdding: boolean) {
    this.tabs.unshift('New');

    if (selectAfterAdding) {
      if (this.selected.value==0)  //if is yet "0"
        this.selected.setValue(1)
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.selected.setValue(0);
      })
    }
 }
```

Comment: Eliseo, Thanks for your reply... You code creates the NEW Tab perfectly, but the created Tab is not active....Can you please check your code again in  the stackblitz link...

Comment: I just forked your stackblitz change the function addTab in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1lz2uy?file=app/tab-group-dynamic-example.ts and works for me :(

Comment: Thank you so much Eliseo... It is working perfectly...

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is to google for

> js array insert at the beginning of an array

You can use `this.tabs.unshift('New');` instead of `this.tabs.push('New');`

Comment: Thanks a lot Canbax... This code is creating the tab as the first tab, but the newly added tab is not selected by default... Can you please help...

Comment: I think changing `this.selected.setValue(this.tabs.length - 1);` to  `this.selected.setValue(0);` should work but it doesn't work. It might be an issue with angular logic

Comment: Thanks a lot Canbax for your reply... Is there any one faced this problem?... Please help...